# kwargs don't do anything

Tags: python, keyword-argument

Could you help me to understand why these keywords arguments do not do anything on the diagram plotting ?
My code does not return any error but it does not take into account these arguments.

```
plot_kwargs = ({'marker': 'o', 'color': 'w', 'mec': 'b', 'linestyle': '-'})

annotate_kwargs = ({'text': 'illuminant'})

plot_planckian_locus_in_chromaticity_diagram(xy, method='CIE 1960 UCS', **plot_kwargs, **annotate_kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working with Colour, you are not supposed to use dict unpacking to pass `plot_kwargs` and `annotate_kwargs`.

From the [documentation](https://colour.readthedocs.io/en/develop/generated/colour.plotting.temperature.plot_planckian_locus_in_chromaticity_diagram.html):

```py
plot_planckian_locus_in_chromaticity_diagram(
    ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    annotate_kwargs=annotate_kwargs,
    plot_kwargs=plot_kwargs
)
```

Comment: Yes I already tried this but it returned an error `Multiple keyword arguments defined, but they do not match the expected count!`